# how do i access textinputs created in .kv file from python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

```
with open("file.kv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())
class content(Screen):
    pass
class resistor(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(content())
sm.add_widget(resistor())

def printthecontentsofthetextinput():
    do something

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return sm
```

and here is my kv file:

```
<resistor>
name:"r"
Image:
    source:"lamp1.jpg"
    allow_stretch:True
    keep_ratio:False
    FloatLayout:
        size:root.width,root.height
        allow_stretch:False
        keep_ratio:False
        Label:
            text:"R"
            color:1,1,1,1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.03,"y":0.23}
            size_hint:0.1,0.05
        TextInput:
            id:rprim
            focus:True
            background_color:0.8,0.96,0.88,1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.23}
            size_hint:0.1,0.05
        Label:
            text:"Ω"
            color:1,1,1,1
            pos_hint:{"x":0.28,"y":0.23}
            size_hint:0.05,0.05
```

i'm trying to access the text input with the id : rprim

i've tried  print(resistor().ids.rprim.text) but that always returns blank even if i have written something in the textinput

Answer (score 0):

Your example has some problems, one of which is that it adds a blank screen on top of the example screen, so nothing is visible.
Other than that, there is no way to *try* to access the `TextInput` from your kv.
Anyway, if you add an `on_text` event, you can check for what is typed.

One way to do this is first to add a callback in your `app` class:

```py
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

    def on_text_input(self, text_input):
        print(text_input.text)
```

.. and then add the callback to the `TextInput`:

```py
            TextInput:
                id:rprim
                focus:True
                background_color:0.8,0.96,0.88,1
                pos_hint:{"x":0.15,"y":0.23}
                size_hint:0.1,0.05
                on_text: app.on_text_input(self)
```

Comment: "it adds a blank screen on top of the example screen, so nothing is visible", could you explain what you mean by this ? thanks.

Comment: Because of the `sm.add_widget(content())` I see an empty black window. This scren 
(an empty one) was the first screen. Since there was no way to change the current screen I had to comment out this line, so I could see the screen with the `TextInput`...

Comment: @pythonier If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too.. ;o)